# virtual memory exhausted while compiling Qt 5.5.1 on raspberry pi 2

Tags: c++, linux, qt, memory, memory-management

I want to test some Qt5 features on raspberry but it wasn't available on the rasbian repositories. So i start to compile the source code on it. After some hours compiling a faced this error:

virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory

here is make output: http://pastebin.com/tGg8wqpZ

It seems that there isn't enough memory but raspberry pi 2 has 1GB of memory. So what should i do to skip this error and continue the compiling process. if there isn't any solution for compiling is there any other way to have Qt5 installed on raspberry?

Comment: Have you read this article? https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt_5.4.1_on_a_Raspberry_Pi

Comment: @VladimirBershov oh! thanks! i'v not seen it before. I was building Qt simply with ./configure and make!